# raster calculation using rasterio

Tags: python, raster-calculator, python-2.7, rasterio

I have a multi image tif with 7 bands and I try to use rastrio package to create a simple calculation.
I follow the docs but that not work for me.

any idea ?

here the code:

```
with rasterio.open('L7.tif') as src:
    #b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = src.read()
    blue = src.read_band(1)
    green = src.read_band(2)
    red = src.read_band(3)
    nir = src.read_band(4)
    profile = src.profile
    profile.update(
        dtype=rasterio.float64,
        count=1,
        compress='lzw')

MI = numpy.zeros(blue.shape)
MI = (blue *green*red *nir  )

with rasterio.open('ndvi_python.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(NDMI.astype(rasterio.float64), 1)
```

error :

```
    blue = src.read_band(1)
AttributeError: 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'read_band'
```

if I try to :

```
with rasterio.open('L7.tif') as src:
    b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = src.read()
```

then I take this error :

```
    b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = src.read()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `read()` method when using Rasterio version 1.0a12 ([Rasterio reference](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/migrating-to-v1.html#removed-src-read-band)).

> The raster array for a raster band can be accessed by calling
>   dataset.read() with the band’s index number. Following the GDAL
>   convention, bands are indexed from 1.

The following is now the preferred method to read raster bands ([Rasterio reference](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/migrating-to-v1.html#removed-src-read-band)):

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('tests/data/RGB.byte.tif') as src:
    data = src.read((1, 2, 3))
    band1 = src.read(1)
```

This will return a Numpy N-D array of the form:

```
>>> band1
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: thank you do much now working but I have one more question.i take this message  `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  NDMI = (blue *green*red *nir )` I think is fro this line `numpy.zeros(blue.shape)` any idea what is this ?

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question with the code that is causing the error. I do not think I would be able to address your question properly in the comments.